# Firewalld open all ports except one

Tags: linux, iptables, ports, firewalld

With `firewalld`, I am trying to allow all ports except one for everyone, as that port must be enabled for a specific host, and I have tried the following:

```bash
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-rich-rule='
rule family="ipv4"
source address="1.2.3.4/32"
port protocol="tcp" port="4567"
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This appears to be an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/397311) - please provide more details, as the terminology as currently written is conflicting: if being done on a non-router OS, all OSes allow all outbound traffic, with some blocking all non-initiating inbound traffic; however, `--zone=public` implies NAT and NAT is only used on a WAN facing device [router] _(unless you're double NAT'd)_.